# RSpec error: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass & undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm learning Test Driven Development with Ruby and RSpec.  My program should find a given word in the text.  The first case should be falsey because the test_word starts with a capital and the second case should be truthy after downcasing it.   When I run the spec file though, I get the

> `undefined method`include?' for nil:NilClass`

method and the

> undefined method  `downcase' for nil:NilClass

error.  How can this be resovled?
Here is my code:

strings_spec.rb:

```
    require_relative 'strings'

RSpec.describe BasicString do

  before do
    @test_word = "Courage"
    @sentecne = "Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts!"

    @text = BasicString.new(@sentence)
  end

  context "case-sensitive" do
  it "should output interpolated text" do
    result = @text.contains_word? @test_word

    expect(result).to be_falsey
    end
  end

  context "case-insensitive" do
  it "should output interpolated text" do
    result = @text.contains_word_ignorecase? @test_word# 'text & 'test_word' were made  instance variables when 'before do' block was added.

    expect(result).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

strings.rb:

```
class BasicString
  attr_reader :sentence

  def initialize(sentence)#The constructor that initializes the instance variable @sentence.
    @sentence = sentence
  end

  def contains_word?(test_word)
    @sentence.include? test_word
  end

  def contains_word_ignorecase?(test_word)
    test_word = test_word.downcase#This line downcases the test word.
    @sentence.downcase.include? test_word#This test_word is downcased again for the instance variable to be sure it's downcased.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling error in your before block: `@sentecne`. So, you end up creating your string with a nil value since `@sentence` hasn't been defined.

Comment: Yep!  That was the problem.  It works now.  Needed a fresh pair of eyes on it.  Thanks again!